# gomobile command error " No android NDK path is set "

Tags: go, gomobile

I am using Go version 1.7.5 in windows and when i am trying to use gomobile command either to install or bind or build . It displays this error-
**"gomobile: no Android NDK path is set. Please run gomobile init with the ndk-bundle installed through the Android SDK manager or with the -ndk flag set."** 
I have added NDK path to system variable $PATH and even installed NDK manually but still the error persist.
Thanks for your time !!

Comment: did you run `gomobile init` as the error massage suggests?

Comment: Reading the docs https://github.com/golang/mobile, it seems gomobile requires golang 1.5.  Your using 1.7.5

Comment: @ymonad while running gomobile init this error is not displayed .

Comment: @reticentroot I have installed golang 1.5 now but now while running gomobile command it shows "gomobile: Go 1.7 or newer is required"

Comment: @SahilChaudhary it looks like you have to do something like  `gomobile init -ndk /path/to/your/android/ndk`

Comment: @ymonad It worked now but during gomobile build command no apk is generated . Can you help with that ?

Comment: @SahilChaudhary maybe you should post another question.

Comment: Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: did it work for Go 1.7 or newer ?

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes, I myself tried it for Go 1.7.5 .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the NDK path in `gomobile init` using the `-ndk` flag - if you follow [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html), the path should be `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/`:

```
gomobile init -ndk ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/
```

Then you can compile the APK:

```
gomobile build -target=android <PATH>
```

The path should be relative to `$GOPATH/src`. For example, if you install the basic example:

```
go get -d golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic
```

The build command should be:

```
gomobile build -target=android golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic
```