# no Android NDK found in $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle nor in $ANDROID_NDK_HOME in Windows 10

Tags: go, android-ndk, gomobile, gomobile-android

I'm following the [official guide](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile) to install gomobile. I have Android Studio installed and via the Android Studio SDK manage installed `NDK (side by side)` and all the SDK packages. Android Studio has no problem compiling and deploying my normal Android apps to me device.

I ran successfully (by which I mean without any errors):

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=auto

gomobile init

go get -d golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic
```

Then I ran:

```
gomobile build -target=android golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic
```

And got the error:

```
gomobile: no Android NDK found in $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle nor in $ANDROID_NDK_HOME
```

When I run as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914874/25282) to another older thread:

```
gomobile init -ndk C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
```

I get:

```
flag provided but not defined: -ndk
usage: gomobile init [-openal dir]
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Have you added path in Environment system variables?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for linux/mac users**

I had the same problem on Linux, and I solved it by making the environment variable like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
```

in this path I have the `ndk-bundle` folder which can also be [downloaded from here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/)

after that i could simply run

```
gomobile bind -x -v .
```

in my project directory and I get the `.aar` file that I want.

Comment: This question is about Windows 10: `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I missed that, thanks. I changed the answer so it appears directed to linux/mac users.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Windows 10 as well.
I fixed it by adding a new environment variable.

1. Press [Windows Key + S] to open the search menu.
2. Search for "Edit the System Environment Variables"
3. Click on "New"  There will be two "New" buttons, you may use the upper one to make it local to your user
4. For Variable name enter: `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`
5. For Variable value enter: `C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk`  (or wherever you installed your NDK, I installed it with Android Studio and it went here by default)

I hesitated to provide this as an answer because I still can't build my Fyne app.
Now I get `no compiler for arm64 was found in the NDK (tried ). Make sure your NDK version is >= r19c. Use sdkmanager --update to update it`

I answered anyway because it does solve the error in question and this next error may be specific to me.